# Export a dictionary containing list of tuples to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I would like to export the following dictionary to csv file:

```py
res_dict = {'A':[(0.1,5),(0.2,6)],'B':[(0.1,3),(0.2,6),(0.6,8),(0.7,9)]}
```

I tried the following code:

```py
    def exportDataToCSV(res):
        with open('XY-data.csv', "wb") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(res.keys())
            for v in res.values():
                writer.writerows(zip(*v))
```

The problem is, that still I must transpose the data in excel sheet to have required view, as follows:

```py
col1 col2 col3 col4
 A         B
0.1   5    0.1   3
0.2   6    0.2   6
           0.6   8 
           0.7   9
```

If possible I would like to avoid using pandas. 
Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.zip_longest`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
res_dict = {'A':[(0.1,5),(0.2,6)],'B':[(0.1,3),(0.2,6),(0.6,8),(0.7,9)]}

def exportDataToCSV(res):
    with open('XY-data.csv', "w") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(res.keys())
        for v in zip_longest(*res.values(), fillvalue=''):
            values = [",".join(map(str,i)) for i in v]
            writer.writerow(values)

exportDataToCSV(res_dict)
```

Comment: Hi, I think that I did not make myself clear regarding output expectations. The idea is to have everything in separate columns. I've updated my previous post. Thanks